# DHT sensors with RGB LED

Tags: temperature-sensor, rgb-led

I have a DHT11 that outputs temperature and humidity values to my serial monitor. I'm trying to serial the **COLOUR** of the light based on the temperature conditions. So far I only get `1`'s and `0`'s. How can I change these integer values to output string say `RED`, `GREEN` or `BLUE`?

**Code**

```
#include <dht.h>

dht DHT;
#define DHT11_PIN A5
int redPin = 10; // Red LED,  connected to digital pin 10
int grnPin = 9; // Green LED, connected to digital pin 9
int bluPin = 8;  // Blue LED, connected to digital pin 8

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Sets the pins as output for RGB LED
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(grnPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  int t = DHT.temperature;
  int h = DHT.humidity;
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.print( "," );
  Serial.print("Humidity = ");
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print("\n");
  delay(60000);
  if((DHT.temperature < 26) && (DHT.temperature >= 23.2)) {
    // Writing the LED colour pins HIGH or LOW to set colours
    digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH); // yellow
    digitalWrite(grnPin, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(bluPin, LOW);
  }
  if((DHT.temperature < 23) && (DHT.temperature > 20.2)) {
    digitalWrite(grnPin, HIGH); // green
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(bluPin, LOW);
  }
  if((DHT.temperature < 20) && (DHT.temperature > 17.2)) {
    digitalWrite(grnPin, HIGH); // aqua
    digitalWrite(bluPin, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
  }
  if(DHT.temperature <= 17) {
    digitalWrite(bluPin, HIGH); // blue
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(grnPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
  }
  delay(1000);
  // Sensor shouldn't be read too frequently so delay of 1s
}
```

I will be grateful if I can get some help. Thanks!

Comment: Add Serial.print() in each block that sets the pins to new values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So far I only get 1's and 0's

Before moving into the LED parts, you have to make sure that your system can correctly read the DHT sensor. There are debugging example from [arduino-info.wikispaces.com](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/DHT11-Humidity-TempSensor)

> How can I change these integer values to output string say RED, GREEN or BLUE?

You can do it by simple `if-else` statement. This would be better than your original code, because there are multiple `if`'s without any `else` which is (although not so significant) less optimal.

So, if put together, you can try:

```
void loop()
{
  int t,h,chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);

  switch (chk)
  {
    case DHTLIB_OK:  
                Serial.print("OK,\t"); 
                break;
    case DHTLIB_ERROR_CHECKSUM: 
                Serial.print("Checksum error,\t"); 
                break;
    case DHTLIB_ERROR_TIMEOUT: 
                Serial.print("Time out error,\t"); 
                break;
    case DHTLIB_ERROR_CONNECT:
        Serial.print("Connect error,\t");
        break;
    case DHTLIB_ERROR_ACK_L:
        Serial.print("Ack Low error,\t");
        break;
    case DHTLIB_ERROR_ACK_H:
        Serial.print("Ack High error,\t");
        break;
    default: 
                Serial.print("Unknown error,\t"); 
                break;
  }
  //moving on into next parts only if you get "OK" from serial reply, which means you successfully read the DHT11
  t = DHT.temperature;
  h = DHT.humidity;
  Serial.print(DHT.humidity, 1);
  Serial.print(",\t");
  Serial.println(DHT.temperature, 1);

  //----end of sensor reading and debugging

  if (t<=17)
  { //blue
   digitalWrite(bluPin, HIGH);   
   digitalWrite(grnPin, LOW);  
   digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);     
   delay(100);
  } else
      if (t<20)
      {
       digitalWrite(grnPin, HIGH);  // aqua  
       digitalWrite(bluPin, HIGH);  
       digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);  
       delay(100); 
      } else
      if (t<23)
      {
        //....  
      }
      //....
      //and goes on

 delay(1000);     
}
```

And yes, as @Matt suggest, it would be better if you use PWM to control the RGB led which will give you (mathematically) 255*255*255 colour possibilities instead of 8 combinations from `digitalWrite()`. For example:

```
//....
//....
  if (t<20)
  { //aqua
   new_t = map(t,DHT11_min_temperature_reading,DHT11_max_temperature_reading,0,255);
   //you can do self research about DHT11 maximum and minimum temperature reading
   //parameters 0 and 255 is the minimum value of PWM(0) and the maximum value(255)
   AnalogWrite(bluPWMPin, new_t);   
   AnalogWrite(grnPWMPin, 255-new_t);  
   AnalogWrite(redPWMPin, 0);     
   delay(100);
  }
//....
//....
```

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `analogWrite()`. You use this with a digital pin and it does Pulse Width Modulation (PWM) which will give you are larger range of colours. Have a look at the Reference page for the function.

You might even be able to use the `map` function (something like that) to 'map' the temperature to the colour values without all the if statements.

Comment: The PWM pins have a `~` next to them on the PCB.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have an idea of how I can implement the map function?

Comment: Erm...  not a clue, I've never used it, but I have seen it on here.